# Other site in web catalog Symfony 2

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, hosting

I have two applications and two domains:

```
- aaatest.com
- bbbtest.com
```

Domain aaatest.com redirect to /home/public_html and have application based on Symfony 2 (working good).

bbbtest.com redirect to /home/public_html/bbbtest and this is simple PHP page with index.php.

Now if I open bbbtest.com then this show me 404 error from Symfony.

Same error is if i open aaatest.com/bbbtest, but if i open open aaatest.com/bbbtest/index.php then second page working good.

I guess by .htaccess in public_html from Symfony2. So how can I open bbbtest without /index.php? I can't modify redirect on my hosting. It must be starting from /public_html.

Comment: post your .htaccess file please.

Comment: post .htacces and hosts configs